# Permission to set to clear logcat

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is there a permission to acquire to clear logcat from the device? The following code is not working

```
ArrayList<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();

commandLine.add("logcat");
commandLine.add("-c");
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine.toArray(new String[2]));
```

Is it event possible to clear logcat?

Answer (score 1):

The only permission related to logs is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

Try putting it to manifest. API says:

> Allows an application to read the low-level system log files. Log entries can contain the user's private information, which is why this permission is 'dangerous'.

So it is definitelly required to read logs, however it is unclear whether it is helpful with clearing the logs.

Comment: I have the read permission set, it gives permission only for reading logs and for not deleting log.

Comment: then as for what I see in the API there is no other permissions for logs. so looks like deleting is unsupported?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for an app to clear logcat on the device.  When you select the 'clear logcat' option in Eclipse/ADT you are not clearing it on the device.

If this changes or if I'm wrong then I hope someone will correct me - I'd be interested to know - but it is unlikely as they are moving Android in the opposite direction: as of JellyBean apps can no longer even read the logcat of other apps, let alone clearing it.